# C# How to stop decimal shift on multiple times through

Tags: c#

I have created a form to arrange a ship hold.

[image]

Problem:  On multiple times through, it comes back with the decimal point shifted two more spaces.  How do I keep it from shifting further?

Code Snippet:

```
private void btnGetInv_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    //if this is a ship hold, roll percentile to get how much of the ship's total weight capacity is being carried.
    if(ShipHold==true)
    {
        decimal Percentage = 0;
        decimal HoldWeight = 0;
        LoNum = 1;
        HiNum = 100;
        DieResult = 0;

        Percentage = DieResult + 1 + RollDice.Next(LoNum - 1, HiNum);
        WeightAvail = Percentage / 100 * WeightAvail;
        HoldWeight = WeightAvail;
        RTBItems.Text = "percentage of weight = " + HoldWeight + "\r\n" + RTBItems.Text;
    }
```

`WeightAvail` is also a `decimal`.  However; `LoNum`, `HiNum`, and `DieResult` are all types `int` to work with the `Random.Next` function.  It might be best if I can round to the nearest whole number.  I'm using Visual Studio 2019.

This was my fix:

```
HoldWeight = Percentage / 100 * WeightAvail;
//HoldWeight = WeightAvail;
RTBItems.Text = "percentage of weight = " + HoldWeight + "\r\n" + RTBItems.Text;

HoldWeight = 0;
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. You say "On multiple times through, it comes back with the decimal point shifted two more spaces" - are you referring to your WeightAvail variable ? Please give example outputs of what you're seeing. Also  you initialize DieResult to 0 and then use that in your calculation - is that intentional ? LoNum is set to 1 but in your RollDice.Next call you have LoNum - 1 so what's the point of this variable ?

Comment: @auburg Thank you for looking at it and asking the clarifying questions.   So to answer your question about DieResult and LoNum:  I am using a modified example for generating random numbers from the Clock.  DieResult + 1 tends to give a little better result but then LoNum becomes 2.  So I have to subtract that one again but only from the low end.  There are times when using that method that LoNum may be higher than 1 e.g. 5.  This is something I remember from about 20 years ago when I was studying C++.

Comment: WeightAvail gets assigned how much a ship can carry based on the Ship Type, then should be passed to this snippet to find out how much the ship in question is actually carrying.

Comment: OK, I think I figured it out.